# Change formula based on selection from dropdown box

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a quick way to make changes on an Excel sheet and I was wondering if someone could enlighten me on an efficient way to solve the following problem.

Say I have a line of three numbers, lets say A1:C1 (However, the data is not in neighbouring columns in the real data set):

```
5, 10, 15
```

I want to have a dropdown box at the end of that line (A4) which shows a list of functions that could be used on these numbers (For example: SUM, AVERAGE, MAX, MIN) and for that to dictate the formula in A5.

A simple way to do this is to create an IF statement and a dropdown box of the possibilities: e.g.

```
= IF($A4 = "average", AVERAGE(A1:A3), IF($A4= "min", MIN(A1:A3), etc..
```

However this is tedious if there is a large number of function choices. So I was wondering if there was a quick way to do this?

Perhaps something like

```
= function(A1:A3)
```

Where function will change dependent on the phrase in the dropdown box, and the dropdown box is contingent on a list of functions held somewhere else on the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting Question. :)

See this example

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

**Code:**

Paste this in a module

```
Function GuessFunction(Rng As Range, FuncType As String) As Variant
    Dim wFn As WorksheetFunction

    GuessFunction = "Error - Please Check Input"

    Set wFn = Application.WorksheetFunction

    Select Case UCase(FuncType)
        Case "AVERAGE": GuessFunction = wFn.Average(Rng)
        Case "SUM": GuessFunction = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case "MAX": GuessFunction = wFn.Max(Rng)
        Case "COUNT": GuessFunction = wFn.Count(Rng)
        '
        '~~> Add More
        '
    End Select
End Function
```

Next enter the formula `=GuessFunction(A1:H1,I1)` in the cell and your are done.

**Output:**

[image]

---

**ALTERNATIVE**

Another way to do what you is to use `EVALUATE`

```
Function GuessFunction(Rng As Range, FuncType As String) As Variant
    GuessFunction = "Error - Please Check Input"
    GuessFunction = Application.Evaluate("=" & FuncType & "(" & Rng.Address & ")")
End Function
```

*PROS:*

You don't have to specify separate code for each formula like we did it in `Select Case` above.

*CONS:*

You can only make it work for formulas like `SUM/MAX/MIN` i.e of type `FORMULA(ADDRESS)`. You cannot use it for say `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 2):

Must you "reinvent the wheel"? Seems all to have been done for you, with Insert > Tables  - Table:

[image: SO21819663 example]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Perhaps my example is a little too simplified. The data is in horizontal, and suffice to say it is not possible to convert them to vertical data. Also the data is not in 3 neighbouring columns, but spaced sporadically, I will change the question to reflect this.