# Excel custom formula not working as expected

Tags: excel-formula

Am basically pretty new to creating custom excel formula's. I have the following custom excel formula:

```
Function Calculate(Quarter As String) As Variant
    Dim wFn As WorksheetFunction
    Dim Rng As Range
    Calculate = "Error - Quarter should be Q1, Q2, Q3 or Q4"

    Set wFn = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    Select Case Quarter
        Case "Q1":
          'Rng = "K" & RowNumber: "P" & RowNumber'
          Rng = K77: P77
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case "Q2":
          'Rng = "R" & RowNumber: "X" & RowNumber'
          Rng = R77: X77
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case "Q3":
          'Rng = "Z" & RowNumber: "AE" & RowNumber'
          Rng = Z77: AE77
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case "Q4":
          'Rng = "AG" & RowNumber: "AM" & RowNumber'
          Rng = AG77: AM77
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        
    End Select
End Function
```

However when i try to use this formula on a cell on my worksheet the output comes as 0. I was trying to refer to this SO post [Change formula based on selection from dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819663/change-formula-based-on-selection-from-dropdown-box).

Could someone please help debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not referencing your cells properly.  Range `K77:P77` is an object so must be `Set`.
As you've written it I think (without `Option Explicit`) it will treat K77 as a variable and P77 as an undefined function (at least that's the errors I got).

The function assumes the ranges are on the same sheet as the function is entered.

```
Function Calculate(Quarter As String) As Variant
    Dim wFn As WorksheetFunction
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Set wFn = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    Select Case Quarter
        Case "Q1":
          'Rng = "K" & RowNumber: "P" & RowNumber'
          Set Rng = Range("K77:P77")
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case "Q2":
          'Rng = "R" & RowNumber: "X" & RowNumber'
          Set Rng = Range("R77:X77")
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case "Q3":
          'Rng = "Z" & RowNumber: "AE" & RowNumber'
          Set Rng = Range("Z77:AE77")
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case "Q4":
          'Rng = "AG" & RowNumber: "AM" & RowNumber'
          Set Rng = Range("AG77: AM77")
          Calculate = wFn.Sum(Rng)
        Case Else
            'Returning errors from functions:
            'http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx
            Calculate = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Darren!